# HTML2PDF: does it support HTML OL tag type?

Tags: php, html, html2pdf

I've the following HTML code:

```
<ol type="A">
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 2</li>
  <li>element 3</li>
  <li>element 4</li>
</ol>
```

Now, my browser displays it as an *alphabetical* ordered list, as follows:

```
A. element 1
B. element 2
C. element 3
D. element 4
```

But when I try to create a PDF using **HTML2PDF** PHP library, I get a *numerical* ordered list:

```
1. element 1
2. element 2
3. element 3
4. element 4
```

Why this? **How can I force HTML2PDF to write the correct ordered list?**

Answer (score 2):

I've worked around the problem by adding the **list-style** CSS rule to the OL tag as follows:

```
.upper-alpha {
  list-style: upper-alpha;
}
```

This let HTML2PDF to render the ordered list with an upper alphabetical index.

However, the issue is still open.

Comment: thanks, but how can i make dl dt by using html2pdf ?